Anime where a mysterious bandaged girl shares her soul with a food truck patron to save his life
What anime is this? In this anime, a young adult male starts off eating at a food truck when he suddenly sees a mysterious girl in bandage wraps, almost like a mummy. An enemy comes for her, and he tries to protect her but ends up getting killed or injured. She then shares a part of her soul to bring him back to life.
From what I remember, if one of them dies, the other gets to live, or something like that. After that, they meet a couple who also did the same thing. The couple trains them and tells them they're partners until one of them dies. She is also a runaway princess from another world.

When did you watch this?

About a couple of months to maybe a year ago that’s why I was asking for the name
